# Using Pig, best way to count numbers within tuples

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm working with tuples of data:

```
dump c;
(20
5
5
)
(1
1
1
5
10
)
```

The output I'm trying to achieve is count the occurrences of each number in total, so like this:

```
 (1,3)
 (5,3)
 (10,1)
 (20,1)
```

I'm attempted this command, and it was unsuccessful:

```
 d = FOREACH c GENERATE COUNT($0);
```

I currently do not have schema for c (not sure that it matters at this point):

```
 describe c;
 Schema for c unknown.
```

Looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Input Tuple:

```
(20 5 5)
(1 1 1 5 10)
```

You could get the count across the tuple by tokenizing and then grouping it.

```
A = LOAD 'file' using TextLoader() as (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) as (line:chararray);    
C = GROUP B BY line;                                                   
D = FOREACH C GENERATE group,COUNT(B);            
dump D;
```

Output:

```
(1,3)
(5,3)
(10,1)
(20,1)
```